# Randomly sample from arbitrarily nested lists while maintaining structure

Tags: python, list, random

I am trying to write a function which chooses integers randomly from arbitrarily nested lists while maintaining order and the structure of the lists (though empty lists can be ignored). The number of samples should be uniformly random from 0 to the number of integers in the nested list.

For example, running `listrand([1,2,3,[3,4],[65,[3]]])` 3 times might give:

```
[1, 3, [3], [65, [3]]]
[1, 2, [[3]]]
[[3, 4], [65]]
```

The catch is I need it to be uniformly distributed, so I can't use something like

```
sample = [[random.sample(mylist)] for mylist in listoflists]
```

because that would be binomial.

At a minimum I need this to work for single-level nesting. I thought about sampling from a flattened list but then I'm not sure how to use those to construct the desired output.

Comment: How important is it that the first output be written as `[1, 3, [3], [65, [3]]]` instead of `[1, 3, [3], [65], [[3]]]`? Also, if both the 3 and the 4 were to be sampled, could we write `[1, 3, [3], [4], [65]]`?

Comment: It's important to keep the sampled items within their original lists. So if `65` is in `list3` and `[3]` is in `list3` then the output should have `[65, [3]]` in the location of `list3`

Comment: OK. Another question: your outputs have different lengths. Does the function choose each value with a certain probability or does it choose a certain number of values with equal probability?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. The number of samples should be uniformly random from 0 to the number of integers in the nested list.

Comment: Are you missing a set of outer brackets? Is the list really `[[1, 3, [3], [65, [3]]], [1, 2, [[3]]], [[3, 4], [65]]]`? Are you wanting a sample from the flattened list or one element of the top-most list of lists and integers?

Comment: I just saw your update.  Are you saying that `k` in `random.sample(x, k)` should be `random.randint(0, len(x))`?

Comment: @dawg those are three separate outputs from each time the function is run. The function should sample from the flattened list, ie. integers, but have output that maintains the structure.

Comment: @James yes, exactly, where len(x) is the length of the flattened list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution satisfies your requirements by construction. In other words, the number of elements chosen is uniformly random.

```
import random
from collections import Iterable

def count(l, r=0):
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, Iterable):
            r += count(i)
        else:
            r += 1
    return r

def listrand(target):
    N = count(target)
    nchosen = random.randint(0, N-1)
    chosen = set(random.sample(range(N), nchosen))

    def build(l, c=0):
        output = []
        for i in l:
            if isinstance(i, Iterable):
                c, sublist = build(i, c)
                if sublist:
                    output.append(sublist)
            else:
                if c in chosen:
                    output.append(i)
                c += 1
        return c, output

    return build(target)[1]
```

Sample output:

```
target = [1,2,3,[3,4], [65,[3]]]

for i in range(5):
    print(listrand(target))

[1, 2, 3, [3, 4], [[3]]]
[2]
[]
[2, 3, [3, 4]]
[[4]]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after! Can you explain why the double `def listrand()` was added?

Comment: @base12masterrace Also a heads up to copy the latest version, as I've made `chosen` a set for a bit of extra speed if the lists are large.